# Google script editor crash on open

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had insert too large array into my google spreadsheet addon script, and now editor page not responding, so I can't revert, and can't run updated code. After reloading all I got is continuous "Script on page not responding" message. Is there any other way to edit script code? Or any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, all I need is wait about half an hour, and this shit script finished at least.

Comment: The two most powerful warriors are patience and time. 
 -Leo Tolstoy

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. the data must be lazy loaded, it must be shredded to the screen during processing.